# Can I dynamically link libraries that have duplicated name of functions?

Tags: assembly, compilation, linker, dynamic-linking

Imagine that *Library1.so* and *Library2.so* has:

```
func1(), func2(), glob_data1, glob_data2
```

***Situation:***
I want use `func1()` and `glob_data1` in *Library1*,
and simultaneously use `func2()` and `glob_data2` in *Library2*.


***Question:***
How can I do that when I dynamically link those libraries?
*(If there's no way on C level, Is there any possible way on assembly level?)*

Comment: What operating system are you programming for?

Comment: @fuz Oh I missed it, I I use Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Imagine that `Library1.so` and `Library2.so` has: `func1(), func2(), glob_data1, glob_data2`

It is generally a *very bad idea* to load both libraries into a single process on Linux (and other UNIX systems).

When e.g. `func1` from `library1` calls `func2`, which `func2` gets called? The answer depends on exactly how the libraries were linked, how they were loaded, and in which order.

If the functions don't call any other exported symbols, you *can* call them via a function pointer obtained from `dlopen` and `dlsym`:

```
void *h1 = dlopen("Library1.so", RTLD_LOCAL|RTLD_LAZY);
int (*f1L1)(void) = dlsym(h1, "func1");

void *h2 = dlopen("Library2.so", RTLD_LOCAL|RTLD_LAZY);
int (*f1L2)(void) = dlsym(h2, "func1");

printf("func1 from Library1 returns %d\n", f1L1());
printf("func1 from Library2 returns %d\n", f1L2());
```

Comment: Hopefully libraries use `hidden` aliases for exported functions, so internal calls within the library don't go through the PLT / symbol-interposition mechanisms.  (And thus are more efficient).  But yeah, some don't.

Answer (score 1):

If these symbols are not meant for use outside of the libraries you can simply mark them as `__attribute((visibility("hidden")))` (or better yet compile your code with `-fvisibility=hidden` and annotate public functions with `__attribute((visibility("default")))`).

If these functions have to remain public you can link your libs with `-symbolic` flag. This would cause linker to resolve references to local definitions (rather than PLT stubs) when possible.

Note that `-symbolic` applies to *all* library symbols. It's possible to achieve the same effect for a subset of symbols using symbol aliases but this is more involved so I'd rather not go into details unless you really need it.